# Insert filepath as hyperlink Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I have a VBA set of code that generates an email and automatically sends it.

One of the things that I cannot get to work properly is putting a hyperlink to a specified folder location within the email.

```
Dim fpath As String

fpath = Worksheets("MS_JRNL_OPEN_TU_FR-4333635").Range("AD5").Value

"file://" & fpath & _
```

Essentially the user has to input a folder location when running the Macro which is in Cell AD5, but I want this is appear as the full folder location as a hyperlink once the email is generated.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are currently using HTMLBody in your email code, it's quite easy to do.  I'll assume you are using code similar to below.  Take note of `strbody` and `.HTMLBody`.  Assuming your `fpath` is formatted like `C:\Users\tjb1\Desktop\file.docx` then you don't need to add anything else to it.  The section creating the hyperlink is `"<A href=" & fpath & ">test link</A>"`.  You can change test link to say whatever you want or change the line to `"<A href=" & fpath & ">" & fpath & "</A>"` to use the path as the link text.

```
Sub MailURL()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    strbody = "<A href=" & fpath & ">test link</A>"
    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "APerson@Somewhere.com"
        .Subject = "Testing URL"
        .HTMLBody = strbody
        .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

I found the code above at [MrExcel](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/492801-putting-active-link-htmlbody-cdo-2.html#post2435236) and just formatted it a bit to work with your variable.

Comment: Thats brilliant, It was the using the path as the link text that I was trying to get sorted. I've looked at MrExcel before but it never came up when I was searching for a solution. Thank you

Comment: Using `HTMLBody` will also include the users signature when it generates the email.  I'm not sure how it works with `.Send` because when I use it I am using `.Display` so the user can enter extra information if needed.  Note that the sample code has `.Send` so you will not see a preview of the email.

Comment: Just something to keep in mind, I've encountered this warning message when making Excel call up Outlook - https://support.office.com/en-us/article/I-get-warnings-about-a-program-accessing-e-mail-address-information-or-sending-e-mail-on-my-behalf-df007135-c632-4ae4-8577-dd4ba26750a2?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US  The fix involved changing the security of the file but I'm not sure how or what as someone else did it.

Comment: I do use .Send and it still attaches the users email signature at the bottom of the email through the exchange server. Haven't encountered that issue before, but if I do I thank you in advance!